# Can't debug/deploy solution from VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, debugging, solution-deployment

I have encountered strange problem on my dev VM.

Background:
Having my VM open (VM Player), I put host computer into sleep mode, then I woke it and put into sleep mode for second time. After waking it up second time, it was slow as hell so I decided to restart it. But since it's responsivenes was close to 0, I used VMware "Power off" option. After rebooting VM, everything seems ok, but in VS 2010 I'm getting:

```
Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: https://xxx.yyy.local. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.
```

I double checked site URL, and user account I'm using:

- is local computer admin,
- is in farm administrators group,
- has `db_owner` role on content database where I deploy,
- has `sysadmin` fixed role on mssql server

I can access site and web application where I try to deploy using browser, however I can't add this site (and any other site) using `SharePoint Connections` in `Server Explorer` - it says: `The site is not available`.

Trying to use powershell cmdlets like Get-SPSite or Get-SPWeb on sites where I'm deploying also finishes with error that site cannot be found.

Cleaning solution, restarting VS, restarting VM doesn't help. Have you ever encountered similar issue and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please attempt the following:

You need change the Site URL from properties tab of your project.

Click to select the project, then press F4 , the properties window will appear, and then change the site URL.

Comment: tried this already changing to existing and non-existing sites and that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved - there were two assemblies on which custom claim provider was dependant and SecurityTokenService was throwing critical exceptions. After putting these two assemblies in GAC using Gacutil, everything was started up.